# Is there a way to make an api using json file data?

Tags: json, rest, api

For example, in my `data.json` file:

```
[
  {
    "course": [
      "science"
    ],
    "units": "3"
  },

  {
    "course": [
      "math"
    ],
    "units": "6"
  }
]
```

I want to write an API that can perform the GET method. For example, I want to make an api url like this:

```
example.com/api/{science or math}
```

it will return another json file that have the corresponding data like this:

```
[
  {
    "course": [
      "science"
    ],
    "units": "3"
  }
]
```

Is there a way to perform this and how?

Answer (score 0):

Find out a git repository called [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) and that is what I need :)